# How do I add an integer to every element of an array

Tags: java, arrays, addition

I'm doing a method called adversary that takes two parameters: an array of ints and a number int and it adds that number to each element of the array

Comment: Iterate over the array and add the integer. What issue are you facing?

Comment: i dont know how to do the  method I've only done:

Comment: public static void add(int[] a, int n )
    {
      
       
    }

Comment: @notfromfl Then the next thing you write is `for` to start the loop needed to iterate over the array. You did learn about `for` loops, right? Perhaps you need to (re)read your Java learning material to remind you want you've learned so far.

Comment: First you need a loop which can iterate over every element in your array! In your loop you need to read out the value of your current index, add your number to the element and then store the new value inside your array by using the current index. Done.

Comment: @Trishul Singh Choudhary The issue is called lack of training and experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void add(int[] a, int n ) { 
    for (int i=0; i<a.length;i++){
         a[i]=a[i]+n;
}}
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks! That worked!!

Comment: however now im having trouble with the next method which is the overloude o this one it uses doubles of array and a double number which gets added to he double array

Comment: @notfromfl you can accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer.

Comment: A double number will get added to each element of a double array.

Comment: This code piece adds an integer to integer array, now you want to add double to double array. What's the problem ? Can you show me what did you try to do ?

Comment: public static void add(double[] a, double n)
    {
        for (int i=0; i <a.length;i++)
        {
         a[i] = a[i] + n;
        }

Comment: Yes, your code looks correct. What's the problem ?

Comment: my bad i had a bracket in the wrong place thanks alot though i havent done java in a long time and i was having a hard time getting this methods done

Comment: Keep learning !!